# Groupby/Split the DataFrame and save it to existing excel files without erasing the data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, openpyxl

I have DataFrame which is like this which i created below as df in below code.

[image]

I have three excel files (Name:- 1C1,1M1,1V1), now i want to split/groupby DataFrame column 'Source' and save the data in new 'Sheet2' without erasing the existing data which is in 'Sheet1'

[image]

```
import glob
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob(r'...\Excel\1*.xlsx'):
    info=pd.read_excel(f)
    df=df.append(info)

for filename in glob.glob(r'...\Excel\1*.xlsx'):
    print(filename)
    book=load_workbook(filename)
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(filename,engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book=book
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

### I have written the code but it is writing the whole DataFrame(all three lines) into all 3 excel files.

### How to write and split/groupby the DataFrame and save it in individual files.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pandas `groupby` you get a collection of the resultant groups.  So, I would:

- implement the `groupby` method to make your groups.
- iterate over the collection.  Note below when you iterate over the collection, you get a tuple result of the group name/criteria and a new data frame with results of the grouping
- Open a new filename for each, using the group name as part of the file or sheet name
- write the group (which is a data frame)

I ginned this up for a separate post to show how to peel the individual groups out of a `groupby` operation.  You can use it as a framework.

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
    ...:                     'value': [2.5, 3, 4.0, 1.1, 2.2]} 
    ...:                     )                                                  

In [29]: df                                                                     
Out[29]: 
  filename  value
0        a    2.5
1        a    3.0
2        a    4.0
3        b    1.1
4        b    2.2

In [30]: groups = df.groupby(['filename'])                                      

In [31]: for f_name, group in groups: 
    ...:     print(f'name of group: {f_name}') 
    ...:     print(group['value']) 
    ...:     print(max(group['value'])) 
    ...:     print() 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                        
name of group: a
0    2.5
1    3.0
2    4.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
4.0

name of group: b
3    1.1
4    2.2
Name: value, dtype: float64
2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i know how Groupby works but i am confused where and how to add groupby function in my above code so that it will not overwrite the existing data and get stored in respective files with new sheet(sheet2).